# Highchart customized x axis values with Group By Year

Tags: highcharts

I want to show Bar Chart x axis Group By year for e.g recently i have a chart like that

http://postimg.org/image/xt6p09d5l/

But i want to Group x axis by year like that mention below in the image

http://postimg.org/image/zas5bthw9/

Do let me know how can i achieve that in Highcharts in the bar chart?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the group-categories extension.

http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/11/Grouped-Categories

```
xAxis: {
        categories: [{
            name: "Fruit",
            categories: ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"]
        }, {
            name: "Vegetable",
            categories: ["Carrot", "Potato", "Tomato"]
        }, {
            name: "Fish",
            categories: ["Cod", "Salmon", "Tuna"]
        }]
    }
```